# Drawing an arc to the canvas android

Tags: android, android-canvas

my arc draws a rectangle on one side, can someone see what i'm doing wrong.

In on draw:

```
@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    progress = this.getProgress();
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, x, y, mPaint);
    canvas.drawArc(mRect, -90, getScale(progress) * 360, true, mBackground);

    if(mProgressBar) {
        //Log.d("PROGRESS", "==> TRUE");
        canvas.drawText("Please Wait", x / 2, y / 2, mText);    
    } else {
        //Log.d("PROGRESS", "==> FALSE");
        canvas.drawText(progress + "%", x / 2, y / 2, mText);   
    }
```

mRect is

```
mRect = new RectF(0 + getPaddingLeft(), 0 + getPaddingTop(), 
                        x - getPaddingRight(), y - getPaddingBottom());
```

[image]

Comment: How do you draw white border?

Comment: Its a drawable   `<com.example.PieProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/progress_bar_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_bar_width"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/white_ring"
            android:indeterminateOnly="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress" >`

Comment: @Leonidos thanks for pointing that out, it looks like something that the dev did in this style caused the issue. I removed the superfluous fields and white border and it draws fine!

Comment: it was the style atrr, removed and working fine, thanks a lot!